# Add option to close vote because it is an XY problem?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I recently saw a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1501143/samsung-magician-software) where the user asked where to buy "Samsung Magician software" for GNU/Linux. A quick google search shows that it is a software for health checkup and performance optimization of Samsung SSDs.

Clearly this is not directly fall into "not an official Ubuntu flavor" (because this is actually about drive optimazation in Ubuntu) or "bug reports about Ubuntu" or something like that.

However, it seems that the user wants to fix a problem (drive optimization == X) using Ubuntu, but they want to use a non-existing solution (samsung magician software == Y), and asked a question about Y. This is another example of the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

We regularly get many similar questions, which don't directly fall into existing categories for closure.

Shall we create a separate closure category for XY problems?

Comment: You could comment or share feedback as unclear. Then you could for the asker to or yourself edit the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if we weren't at our limit [as Thomas said](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/20445/618353), I don't think that XY questions that need to be closed occur frequently enough that they would need a new closure reason.

The best option would be, in my opinion, to close such questions with a custom closure reason. To do that:

1. Click *Close* below a question.
2. Select **A community-specific reason**:

   > [image]
3. Select **Other - add a comment**:

   > [image]
4. There you can add your custom reason for closing the question. For example:

   > I'm voting to close this question because it is an [XY problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).
5. Click the *Vote to close* button.

Comment: That is what I had done for this question!

Answer (score 6):

We're currently at our limit of "custom close reasons".  Compared to the other close reasons we have, I don't see XY problem posts as frequently happening enough to warrant removing one of our existing close reasons to replace it with XY as a closure reason.